# Socket Program in ipad

Tags: ipad

I want a simple Socket program for Client(ipad)/Server(Mac or pc) communication
by using Network.

Anybody know please Help me....

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see this open-sourced library: https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket